# Words that mean "obsessed with theory" and "obsessed with data"

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, terminology, translation

I'm looking for one-word terms to describe someone obsessed with theory and someone obsessed with data. We use the Spanish terms 'teoricón' and 'datoso' which roughly translate to 'theorophile' and 'dataphile' (respectively) but I'm not sure if these are acceptable/clear to native English speakers.

Comment: I don't know if yoy can attach the *-phile* suffix to any and all words in English. It's not an English suffix as such. ...

Comment: ... In any case, *-phile* is not about obsession, *-mania* is.

Comment: You'd likely say "theoretician" (or "theoreticist" or "academic") and "empiricist" (or "pragmatist"), or perhaps "inductivist" and "deductivist").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Dan Bron suggests in his comment above, one common way to express the split between a focus on theory and a focus on data is with *theoretical* and *empirical*; others are *abstract* and *concrete*, and *idea-driven* and *number-driven*.

Though the two words doesn't describe precisely the same split as "obsessed with theory" and "obsessed with data" I also like the contrasting pair *noumenalist* and *phenomenalist*. According to *Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* the Greek root of *noumenon* refers to "that which is apprehended by thought" while the root of *phenomenon* refers to that which appears. However, this pair is not in common use.